# Pong and Breakout games

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, game, turtle-graphics

So I have made 2 games without any internet when on vacation. I have used turtle because I did not install pygame. I was wondering how I could improve my games. Here is the code:

Pong:

```py
from turtle import *
from time import sleep
import random, keyboard, math

setup(width=800, height=700)

if(input('Do you want to have a AI? (Y or N) ') == 'Y'):
    Ai = True
else:
    Ai = False

ts = getscreen()
ts.bgcolor('black')
title('Pong')

P1_Score = 0
P2_Score = 0
Paddle_2_dir = 225
Paddle_1_dir = -45
Paddle_2_y_bot = 0
Paddle_2_y_top = 0
Paddle_1_y_bot = 0
Paddle_1_y_top = 0
Ball_y = 0
random_range = []
random_int = 0
in_section = False

if(Ai == True):
    for i in range(-90, 90):
        random_range.append(i)

Score = Turtle()
Paddle_1 = Turtle()
Ball = Turtle()
Paddle_2 = Turtle()

Score.speed(1000)
Paddle_1.speed(1000)
Ball.speed(1000)
Paddle_2.speed(1000)

Score.ht()

Score.color('white')
Paddle_1.color('white')
Ball.color('white')
Paddle_2.color('white')

Score.pu()
Paddle_1.pu()
Ball.pu()
Paddle_2.pu()

Score.goto(0, 290)
Paddle_2.goto(350, 0)
Paddle_1.goto(-350, 0)
Ball.goto(0, 0)

Score.shape("circle")
Paddle_2.shape("square")
Paddle_2.shapesize(stretch_wid=8, stretch_len=1, outline=None)
Paddle_1.shape("square")
Paddle_1.shapesize(stretch_wid=8, stretch_len=1, outline=None)
Ball.shape("circle")

Ball.seth(0)

Score.write(f"{P1_Score} | {P2_Score}", False, align="center", font='Arial 35 normal')

print('Started!')

def Win(Winner):
    Score.clear()
    Score.write(f"{Winner} Wins!", False, align="center", font='Arial 35 normal')
    ts.bgcolor('red')
    ht()
    sleep(0.5)
    ts.bgcolor('blue')
    sleep(0.5)
    ts.bgcolor('yellow')
    sleep(0.5)
    ts.bgcolor('green')
    sleep(2)
    bye()

while True:
    Ball.fd(5)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('up'):
        Paddle_2.goto(350, Paddle_2.ycor() + 8)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
        Paddle_2.goto(350, Paddle_2.ycor() - 8)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        Paddle_1.goto(-350, Paddle_1.ycor() + 8)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        Paddle_1.goto(-350, Paddle_1.ycor() - 8)

    if(Ball.xcor() > 400):
        Score.clear()
        P1_Score += 1        
        Ball.goto(0, 0)
        Ball.seth(180)
        Paddle_2.sety(0)
        Paddle_1.sety(0)
        Score.write(f"{P1_Score} | {P2_Score}", False, align="center", font='Arial 35 normal')
    elif(Ball.xcor() < -400):
        Score.clear()
        P2_Score += 1
        Ball.goto(0, 0)
        Ball.seth(0)
        Paddle_2.sety(0)
        Paddle_1.sety(0)
        Score.write(f"{P1_Score} | {P2_Score}", False, align="center", font='Arial 35 normal')

    if(round(Ball.xcor()) < 0 and in_section == False and Ai == True):
        random_int = random.choice(random_range)
        fail = random.randint(1, 18)
        fail_distance = random.randint(10, 30)
        in_section = True
    elif(round(Ball.xcor()) > 0 and in_section == True and Ai == True):
        in_section = False

    if(round(Paddle_1.ycor()) != round(Ball.ycor()) and Ai == True and round(Ball.xcor()) < 0):
        if(fail == 1):
            Paddle_1.sety(Ball.ycor() + (100 + fail_distance))
        elif(fail == 2):
            Paddle_1.sety(Ball.ycor() - (100 + fail_distance))
        else:
            Paddle_1.sety(Ball.ycor() + random_int)

    if(Ball.xcor() >= Paddle_2.xcor() and Ball.xcor() <= Paddle_2.xcor() + 5):
        Paddle_2_y_top = round(Paddle_2.ycor())
        Paddle_2_y_top += 90

        Paddle_2_y_bot = round(Paddle_2.ycor())
        Paddle_2_y_bot -= 90

        Ball_y = round(Ball.ycor())
        
        Paddle_2_dir = 225
        
        for i in range(Paddle_2_y_bot, Paddle_2_y_top):

            Paddle_2_dir -= .5
            
            if(int(round(Ball_y)) == int(round(i))):
                Ball.seth(Paddle_2_dir + 0.5)
                break

    if(Ball.xcor() <= Paddle_1.xcor() and Ball.xcor() >= Paddle_1.xcor() - 5):
        Paddle_1_y_top = round(Paddle_1.ycor())
        Paddle_1_y_top += 90

        Paddle_1_y_bot = round(Paddle_1.ycor())
        Paddle_1_y_bot -= 90

        Ball_y = round(Ball.ycor())

        Paddle_1_dir = -45
        
        for i in range(Paddle_1_y_bot, Paddle_1_y_top):

            Paddle_1_dir += .5
            
            if(int(round(Ball_y)) == int(round(i))):
                Ball.seth(Paddle_1_dir - 0.5)
                break

    if(round(Paddle_2.ycor()) >= 310):
        Paddle_2.goto(350, 300)
    elif(round(Paddle_2.ycor()) <= -310):
        Paddle_2.goto(350, -300)
    if(round(Paddle_1.ycor()) >= 310):
        Paddle_1.goto(-350, 300)
    elif(round(Paddle_1.ycor()) <= -310):
        Paddle_1.goto(-350, -300)

    if(round(Ball.ycor()) >= 320 or round(Ball.ycor()) <= -320):
        Ball.seth(-Ball.heading())

    if(P1_Score == 3):
        Win('Player 1')
        print('Finished!')
        break
    if(P2_Score == 3):
        Win('Player 2')
        print('Finished!')
        break

    if keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
        while True:
            if not keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
                break

        while True:
            keyboard.wait('Esc')
            while keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
                sleep(0.1)
            break
```

Breakout:

```py
from turtle import *
from time import sleep
import random, keyboard, math

ht()
setup(width=800, height=700)

Block_color_row_len = 0
Block_Place_X = 0
Block_Place_y = 0
Blocks = 0
Lives = 3
Alive_blocks_int = 0
Resets = 0
Prev_x = 0
Prev_y = 0
new_x = 0
new_y =0

Ball_x = 0

Paddle_dir = 135
Paddle_x_right = 0
Paddle_x_left = 0

Block_pos = [(-350,250), (-250,250), (-150,250), (-50,250), (50,250), (150,250), (250,250), (350,250),
             (-350,210), (-250,210), (-150,210), (-50,210), (50,210), (150,210), (250,210), (350,210),
             (-350,170), (-250,170), (-150,170), (-50,170), (50,170), (150,170), (250,170), (350,170),
             (-350,130), (-250,130), (-150,130), (-50,130), (50,130), (150,130), (250,130), (350,130),
             (-350,90), (-250,90), (-150,90), (-50,90), (50,90), (150,90), (250,90), (350,90)]
Block_default = [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
Block_y = [250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250,
           210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210,
           170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170,
           130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130,
           90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90]
Block_x = [-350, -250, -150, -50, 50, 150, 250, 350,
           -350, -250, -150, -50, 50, 150, 250, 350,
           -350, -250, -150, -50, 50, 150, 250, 350,
           -350, -250, -150, -50, 50, 150, 250, 350,
           -350, -250, -150, -50, 50, 150, 250, 350]
Block_color_row = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
Block_color = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
Block_color_cur = []
Block_alive = []

Blocks = len(Block_pos)

def Block(Turtle, Color):
    Block_Place_X = Turtle.xcor() - 40
    Block_Place_y = Turtle.ycor() - 10

    Turtle.goto(Block_Place_X, Block_Place_y)
    Turtle.color(Color)
    Turtle.begin_fill()
    Turtle.pd()

    Turtle.goto(Block_Place_X, Block_Place_y + 20)
    Turtle.goto(Block_Place_X + 80, Block_Place_y + 20)
    Turtle.goto(Block_Place_X + 80, Block_Place_y)
    Turtle.goto(Block_Place_X, Block_Place_y)

    Turtle.end_fill()
    Turtle.pu()
    Turtle.goto(Block_Place_X + (Block_Place_X / 2), Block_Place_y + (Block_Place_y / 2))

def New(Turtle):
    global Block_pos, Block, Block_color, Block_color_row_len, Block_color_cur, Block_default, Block_alive, Blocks

    Turtle.clear()

    Block_color_row_len = len(Block_color_row)
    Block_color_cur = []
    Block_alive = Block_default

    for i in range(Block_color_row_len):
        for a in range(Block_color_row[i]):
            Block_color_cur.append(Block_color[i])
    
    for i in range(Blocks):
        Turtle.goto(Block_pos[i])
        
        Block(Turtle, Block_color_cur[i])

ts = getscreen()
ts.bgcolor('black')
title('Breakout')

Block_Creator = Turtle()
Paddle = Turtle()
Ball = Turtle()

Block_Creator.color('black')
Paddle.color('brown')
Ball.color('white')

Block_Creator.pu()
Paddle.pu()
Ball.pu()

Block_Creator.speed(1000)
Paddle.speed(1000)
Ball.speed(1000)

Block_Creator.goto(0, 0)
Paddle.goto(0, -300)
Ball.goto(0, 0)

Block_Creator.ht()

Paddle.shape("square")
Paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=8, outline=None)
Ball.shape("circle")

New(Block_Creator)

Ball.seth(270)

while True:
    prev_x = round(Ball.xcor())
    prev_y = round(Ball.ycor())
    
    Ball.fd(8)

    new_x = round(Ball.xcor())
    new_y = round(Ball.ycor())
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a') or keyboard.is_pressed('left') and not Paddle.xcor() < -350:
        Paddle.bk(8)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('d') or keyboard.is_pressed('right') and Paddle.xcor() < -340:
        Paddle.fd(8)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('d') or keyboard.is_pressed('right') and not Paddle.xcor() > 350:
        Paddle.fd(8)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('a') or keyboard.is_pressed('left') and Paddle.xcor() > 340:
        Paddle.bk(8)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
        bye()
        break

    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        Ball.goto(random.choice(Block_pos))

    if(round(Ball.ycor()) <= Paddle.ycor() and round(Ball.ycor()) >= Paddle.ycor() - 4):
        Paddle_x_right = round(Paddle.xcor())
        Paddle_x_right += 90

        Paddle_x_left = round(Paddle.xcor())
        Paddle_x_left -= 90

        Ball_x = round(Ball.xcor())
        
        Paddle_dir = 135
        
        for i in range(Paddle_x_left, Paddle_x_right):

            Paddle_dir -= .5
            
            if(int(round(Ball_x)) == int(round(i))):
                Ball.seth(Paddle_dir + 0.5)
                break
    if(round(Ball.ycor()) >= 80):
        for i in range(Blocks):
            for a in range(Block_x[i] - 50, Block_x[i] + 50):
                if(round(Ball.xcor()) == a):
                    for f in range(Block_y[i] - 25, Block_y[i] + 25):
                        if(round(Ball.ycor()) == f):
                            if(Block_alive[i] == True):
                                Block_alive[i] = False
                                Block_Creator.goto(Block_pos[i])
                                Block(Block_Creator, 'black')
                                Ball.sety(Ball.ycor() + 0.01)
                                Ball.sety(Ball.ycor() - 0.01)
                                Ball.seth(-Ball.heading())

    if(Ball.ycor() < -370):
        if(Lives >= 1 and Lives != 0):
            Lives -= 1
            Ball.seth(270)
            Ball.goto(0, 0)
            Paddle.setx(0)
            for i in range(3):
                Ball.color('red')
                sleep(0.2)
                Ball.color('white')
                sleep(0.2)
        if(Lives == 0):
            Ball.seth(270)
            Ball.goto(0, 0)
            Paddle.setx(0)
            Ball.color('red')
            sleep(2)
        
    if(Lives <= 0 or Resets > 3):
        # End game event here
        bye()
        break

    if(round(Ball.ycor()) >= 330):
        Ball.seth(-Ball.heading())
    if(round(Ball.xcor()) >= 400 or round(Ball.xcor()) <= -400):
        Ball.seth(-Ball.heading() + 180)

    Alive_blocks_int = 0
    
    for i in range(Blocks):
        if(Block_alive[i] == False):
            Alive_blocks_int += 1

    if(Alive_blocks_int == 40):
        Resets += 1
        New(Block_Creator)
        Ball.goto(0, 0)
        Ball.seth(270)
        Paddle.setx(0)
        Block_alive = Block_default
```

Both of the games work fine, but if you hit the side of the block the angle calculations do not work and it knocks out the entire row. That's a minor issue I still need to work out, but overall it seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to code review where we review code that is working as expected that you have written and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. Due to `glitches` this question is off-topic. Please read our [guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pacmaninbw Is it really off-topic when the question is not about fixing the glitches? Any program could have bugs and errors and still be functional. I think there's lots that can be improved in this code, regardless of game glitches.

Comment: @user985366 There were 2 votes to close this question when I first saw it, there are now 4 votes to close out of the necessary 5. Unfortunately you can't see this because you don't have the rep yet. I'm not the first or the last to thing the glitches make it off-topic.

Comment: I removed the word 'glitches', lets just say its a combo move if you hit the side of the block lol.

Comment: What is it you want out of this question? Do you want us to remove the combo move? Do you want to know ways your code can be improved without touching the combo move?

Comment: Both, i just want to make the code more effective and shorter and remove the combo move.

Comment: We can't do that. I'll remove all off-topic requests, that's the only way we can make this work. The alternative is closing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For Pong:

```
if(input('Do you want to have a AI? (Y or N) ') == 'Y'):
    Ai = True
else:
    Ai = False
```

This can be shortened to simply

```
ai = input('Do you want to have a AI? (Y or N) ').upper() == 'Y'
```

`==` already evaluates to `True`/`False`, so using it in a condition then dispatching to `True`/`False` is redundant. I also added in a call to `upper` so the user can enter either case of "y" and it will still work.

---

```
random_range = []

if(ai == True):
    for i in range(-90, 90):
        random_range.append(i)
```

A few things to note:

- Similar to before, comparing against `True` using `==` is redundant. `ai` will either be `True` or `False` already, which is what `ai == True` would evaluate to to anyways. `if ai:` is fine.
- If you're ever simply `append`ing to a list in a loop, you should consider using a list comprehension instead. Here though, your intent is just to turn the `range` into a list, so `random_range = list(range(-90, 90))` will work fine.
- `random_range` is only ever used later if `ai == true`. You could unconditionally create the list instead of checking what `ai` is. Ya, that wastes a little bit of time, but for such a small list, the time should be negligible.

---

---

## For Breakout:

I'd use "list multiplication" to neaten up all the massive lists you have at the top. For example, `Block_default` can be :

```
block_default = [True] * (5 * 8)  # Or just [True] * 40
```

And similarly, `Block_y` could be something like:

```
block_y = [row
           for val in range(250, 89, -40)  # Generate each of the vals
           for row in [val] * 8]  # Use list multiplication, then flatten
```

If you make some variables at the top that store the height and width of the block of blocks, you can use them instead, and also use some more sequence operations like [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to *greatly* reduce duplication:

```
BLOCKS_WIDTH = 8
BLOCKS_HEIGHT = 5

block_default = [True] * (BLOCKS_HEIGHT * BLOCKS_WIDTH)

block_y = [row
           for val in range(250, 89, -40)
           for row in [val] * BLOCKS_WIDTH]

block_x = list(range(-350, 351, 100)) * BLOCKS_HEIGHT

# Take the two existing coordinate lists, and "zip" them together
block_pos = list(zip(block_x, block_y))
```

Also note, I fixed up your names. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) says that plain variables should be in "snake_case"

Beyond that though, I haven't used Turtle in forever, so I can't comment on much else.

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot!

Comment: And I am still new to python so I did not know about PEP8.

Comment: @DrakeFletcher No problem. Glad to help. And PEP8 is Python's style guide, and should be followed when possible. I'd just give a quick read through. Most of it is pretty common sense, and you can always check back on it later for general guidelines for particular cases. If you use an IDE like Pycharm as well, you'll automatically get PEP8 style suggestions.